# best method to refresh live data value in fragment in kotlin

Tags: repository, fragment, android-room, android-livedata, reload

I have all lists in fragment  - Live Data values obtained from the Room, through the Repository.
I want to reload the values in every 30 minutes in fragment page. How to do it in kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick, using the `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes:

```
val timer = Timer()
val timerTask = object : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        // refresh live data here
    }
}

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask , 0, 30 * (60*1000)) // Runs every 30 minutes
```

Comment: sorry, but its not update my lists adapter in UI. is there anyother method available????